# Why is calculator showing math error while calculating $\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt x}dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

While calculating $\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt x}dx$ in a calculator (Casio 991 ES Plus), it shows `MATH ERROR`. But clearly$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt x}dx=\left[\frac{x^{-\frac 12+1}}{-\frac 12+1}\right]_0^1=\left[2\sqrt x\right]_0^1=2$$
Then why does the calculator show error output?

Comment: maybe it's just not programmed to deal with improper riemann integrals?

Comment: digital devices use numerical approach algorithm to calculate integrals, they don't know how to calculate antiderivatives. If you use wolfram, maybe it works.

Comment: @UESTCfresh This is false. Wolfram or Mathematica (as well as many other similar software) run on digital devices and know how to calculate integrals better than i do.

Comment: @worldsmithhelper I think mathematica is more like a complex software, however, calculators such as Casio 991 ES Plus may only use some simple numerical approach algorithm to solve all things.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you specify the exact model of calculator and firmware i can only speculate. It is likely that it encounters a division by zero when evaluating the function to integrate at 0. As $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ at $x=0$ is undefined and it would be quiet surprising if an integrator doesn't evaluate the function at the borders of the interval it is supposed to integrate on.
See if the math error vanishes if you start integration from a very small number larger then 0 such as 2.220446049250313e-16.

The [manual](https://cdn3.evostore.io/documents/fusion/fus485787manual.pdf) of calculator you use says it uses the [Gauss-Kronrod method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Kronrod_quadrature_formula). Which evaluates the integrand directly. It looks like this method also evaluates the expression on the interval borders you integrate over. So the calculator tries to evaluate  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{0}}$ and fails.